# Using mysql: column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql, and can not figure out why this error keeps coming up. It's a simple table and I want id to be 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. alongside two other columns. Why does it keep reading, column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

```
CREATE DATABASE thedatabase;

USE thedatabase;

CREATE TABLE cars (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    model INTEGER NOT NULL,
    mileage INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO thedatabase.cars (
    model,  
    mileage
) VALUES (
    (45, 34598), 
    (22, 23847),
    (10, 3847), 
    (487, 93229),
    (237, 238975),
    (23, 23987),
    (34, 3498),
    (57, 34984),
    (56, 34983),
    (20, 9845);
```

Comment: is this your real statement? THere is a `)` missing

Comment: at the end? I amended this and still throws up same error

Comment: @Merialc Read Darshan's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have got an extra opening bracked in `INSERT` statement, after `VALUES` below should work fine:

```
INSERT INTO thedatabase.cars ( model,
mileage ) VALUES (45, 34598), (22, 23847), (10, 3847), (487, 93229), (237, 238975), (23, 23987), (34, 3498), (57, 34984), (56, 34983), (20, 9845);
```

Comment: Most typo questions should be closed rather than answered.